# gulp doens't ignore node_modules when compiling ts

Tags: typescript, gulp

i want to compile my typescript files. I specified an excluded folder in my tsconfig.json but this is ignored by gulp-typescript.

so i get this error:
node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.webworker.d.ts(1870,6): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'XMLHttpRequestResponseType'.

tsc tries to compile the node_modules...

here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs"
},
"exclude": [
    "node_modules"
]
}
```

gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var less = require("gulp-less");
var ts = require("gulp-typescript")
var sourcemaps = require("gulp-sourcemaps");

const tsProject = ts.createProject("tsconfig.json");

gulp.task("less", function () {
    gulp.src('http/webroot/**/*.less')
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(function (f){
            return f.base;
        }))
});

gulp.task("tsc", function () {
    var tsResult = gulp.src("**/*.ts")
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(tsProject())

    return tsResult.js
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write(""))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(function (f){
        return f.base;
    }));
});

gulp.task("default", ['less', "tsc"], function () {
    gulp.watch(".less", ["less"]);
});
```

this is my sourcetree:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try adding ignore in your gulpfile

```
gulp.task('default', function(){
                            //
                           //
                          //
        },
        ignore: ['./node_modules/**']
```